# SQL Text column holds a date. How to convert to get actual date from the text?

Tags: php, sql, date, type-conversion

Here is my code and my problem.  When i run the SQL Query it is showing (for current month i'm writing this) not only this current year but also the previous (2018) year and I assume there is a problem with the way i'm converting the dates?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?
$fdaymonth = (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('m/d/Y');
$ldaymonth = (new DateTime('last day of this month'))->format('m/d/Y');
$currmonthname = Date('F');
?>
<hr />
<p class="pull-left txt-color-blueLight">Marked in system as sold in <?=$currmonthname;?>: 
<?   
$query = "SELECT source,count(*) as total
FROM apps
WHERE date_sold BETWEEN '" . $fdaymonth . "' and '" . $ldaymonth . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)== 0) echo "<strong>Error</strong>"; 

                    // Print out result
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<b class=\"badge bg-color-greenLight\">" . $row['total'] . "</b>";
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: What language is this?  PHP?  Python? Javascript?  I don't anything that takes a string "first day of this month" as a parameter to the constructor

Comment: What's your backend database, and how are the relevant columns defined?

Comment: You're using `mysqli_query` but the syntax is SQL Server (`convert` with 3 args).

Comment: Salman A could you give me an example?  So the problem is the SQL Query itself?  The database backend is MySQL

Comment: And yes it's PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CAST($fdaymonth AS DATE) AND CAST($ldaymonth AS DATE)

Comment: Sadly when adding that to my SQL statement it's showing no results

Answer (score 0):

I wound up adding a new column and converting the TEXT column dates into a DATE column to more easily convert.  The date_sold column was a TEXT column but was holding an actual date in a DD/MM/YYYY format which was causing the conflict.  Now that it's a DATE formatted SQL column i'm able to get the results i want.  Thanks everyone.